# Mouse and keyboard is not working in VMware

Tags: macos, keyboard, mouse, vmware-workstation

I installed Mac OS X in VMware. With that setup, Mac's mouse as well as keyboard is not working in VMware.

How do I get my mouse and keyboard working?

Comment: I thought it was illegal running Mac OS (any version) on VMs. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae OS X's EULA has allowed running OS X VMs on Macs (but not on non-Mac computers) since 10.7.